# Do JAX WS' DIIs like Dispatch get impacted while migrating from JAVA 7 to 8

Tags: java, web-services, soap, java-8

We are using in Java,

```
 javax.xml.ws.Dispatch<SOAPMessage>
```

which is essentially a Dynamic invocation Interface for invoking a web service.
The Javadoc states following description:

```
 The Dispatch interface provides support for the dynamic invocation of a service endpoint operations. 
The javax.xml.ws.Service class acts as a factory for the creation of Dispatch instances.

Since:
JAX-WS 2.0
```

We are migrating from Java 7 to 8.

Do Dynamic Invocation Interface involve Java Native Code?

or Is it true that the arguments are passed in native form?

Let me know if more information is needed to answer

**I had a more general question earlier. As my understanding was improved with the help of @EJP, I have modified the question to be more precise.**

Comment: Whenever you want to know about such things, studying the documentation should be the first choice, then you may ask *specific* questions. Besides that, I don’t know why you are asking about “native” code or forms as you are talking about a migration between Java versions, not between hardware architectures, aren’t you?

Comment: I searched in google about Direct Invocation interface. Most of the information is pertaining to CORBA. Secondly, reason I am asking is because for some reason a colleague says its pertaining to Native Java Code and it may get impacted. I did not find anything like that so thought about checking here. Thank you for your comment though.

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea what your “Direct Invocation Interface” is and already know that there are no google matches for that, only phrases which have some words in common. But since *you* say you are using it, *you* must have an idea of what it is and also hands on some documentation. At least, you should known who provided the software you are using, thus, where to search/ask for documentation…

Comment: Oops. That was a mistake. It's Dynamic Invocation Interface.

Comment: Dynamic Invocation Interface is part of CORBA. Do you mean the JNI Dynamic Invocation ***API***? It doesn't seem likely if you're also talking about Web services. More probably you have mis-tagged this question as JNI when you're talking about CORBA. And in any case neither CORBA nor JNI has changed incompatibly in Java 8. Possibly your colleague is confused, or doesnt know what he's talking about,

Comment: Removed JNI tag. I am tending to agree with you.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't you asking about the JAX-WS DII `javax.xml.ws.Dispatch`, and not the CORBA DII? You should remove the Corba tag from the question if you're not referring to the Corba DII.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your colleague is confused. Dynamic Invocation Interface is part of CORBA, not JNI. CORBA does not change with Java releases, and has not changed incompatibly in Java 8, or indeed ever. Neither has JNI since about 1997 actually, or in fact any other aspect of Java whatsoever, in any incompatible way other than security fixes. Java 1.1.8 code still runs. If your colleague has some evidence for his claims let him produce them.

Comment: Can you share with me some credible source which states that Dynamic Invocation Interfaces are part of CORBA only or comes from CORBA part of Java Platform?

Comment: The Corba Specification contains DII, but I haven't said anything about 'Corba *only*'. The question is really whether something has changed incompatibly in Java 8. Let those who think so prove it.

Comment: DII appears to be a more general concept. I agree that DIIs in CORBA have not changed. I am actually concerned about DIIs provided in JAXWS although this is a fact that I was not aware of when I asked the question. Your answer is still helpful.